# ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account

Tags: solidity, contract-development, chainlink

Documenting a solution for an error message received while working on a Chainlink contract:

**Error Message**

```
ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted: function call to a non-contract account
```

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution**

This problem was occurring because of the setPublicChainlinkToken() method.

I was attempting to deploy my API Consumer contract on my localhost network. The [API reference](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-framework/#setpublicchainlinktoken) states, at the time of writing:

> “This method will only set the LINK token address if the calling
> contract is on a public network.”

After switching to the Kovan Testnet, the problem was solved.